# What lexical item means to "Transfer, ( a legal case or action) to a higher court?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary

The initial, medial and terminal letters are e-v-e.
I have to chose from the following words:

Omniscient Equivocate Loquacious Garrulous Verbose Linguistics Paucity Equity Soliloquy Prescient Eloquent Colloquy Bilingual Evoke Provocation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't provide solutions for puzzles.

Comment: This sounds like question on a crossword puzzle.

Comment: I'm honestly confused about what the question is asking... Equivocate seems like the only word that starts with an E, has a V relatively in the middle, and ends with an E...

Comment: @myacorn which of these words might mean to Transfer to a higher court?

Comment: None, that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submit for your consideration **elevate**, meaning to raise to a higher level.

Comment: But it's not in the OP's list.

Comment: Most of the words there don't fit the criterion e-v-e either. Only equivocate and evoke do. Unless the OP explains, the question itself is more of a mystery than what it asks.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty This is excerpted from an English Morphology textbook. We are supposed to go through some words, and then there are exercises. A meaningful sentence is given, and the learner is supposed to relate the meaning to one of the words he/she has studied. Of course there are clues like e-v-e to facilitate the job. Smallness of number or quantity; fewness, scantiness has clues: p-c-y and there is a blank to be filled, so naturally the word should be paucity. I don't know about this e-v-e, I have written evoke for my answer, but I'm afraid it won't be the right answer.